# converting xdoc or xelement into string?

Tags: c#, xml

can you easily convert an xdocument and xelement into string to store in the db?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341005.aspx) or [`ToString(SaveOptions)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb551415.aspx)?

There are various alternatives depending on what you want to do, but those are the simplest :)

Comment: +1 It's so simple it might just work!

Answer (score 1):

In you want the **content** of the element you could use **.InnerText** or if you want the **XML of the element** you could use **.InnerXml**